# Add Link to NavDropdown react bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to add a Link from the react-router-dom directory

For NavDropdown from the react bootstrap 5 library

I tried to find a guide but it doesn't work for me

What am I doing wrong?

```
<NavDropdown
title="In store restaurant"
id="basic-nav-dropdown"
as={Link}
to="/InStoreRestaurant"
 renderMenuOnMount={true}
  >
...
```

Thank you